# When I send the command npm start it is Compiled with error

Tags: reactjs

This is the error while I'm compiling I don't know what I should do..I tried different ways but I couldn't.

ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:0-33
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../AppUi which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

I tried to do a symlink but I guess I do something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In `./src/index.js`, you're doing an `import ../AppUi`.

This isn't going to work, because AppUi is outside of your `src` directory.

Move AppUi inside src, and update the `import ../AppUi` line to only have one full-stop (`.`) instead of two (`..`) at the start